# How to read if USB cables or relay are connected or not using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, usb, device

I have usb cable connected to pc. This is not device, only cables.
I need to know if some of them are connected or not using c# program.
I dont know which cables. If some of usb pins (i dont know which) are connected c# app should show ON and if are not connected to itself - OFF.
Or maybe should i use for that purpose some ftdi usb to com cable?
I have only usb ports in PC.
I dont know about it too much. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the standard USB2.0, USB 3.0? Where did you get this information?

Comment: A lone cable can not be detected. A cable can be used to connect a device, and that device can be detected. If you don't even know that, then I fear you will not be very successful. But if you want to try, here goes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303342(v=vs.85).aspx and: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263883?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Comment: i also have this cable: USB RS232 COM CH340 https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-CH340T/resources/CH340DS1.PDF  can i use it to detect if two wires are connected?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the closest you can get to the functionality you are seeking is:

```
string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

This will return you a list of names of the COM-ports of the connected devices. 
You will need some sort of user input to figure out how many cables are connected and use that info along with `ports` to make your application.

Detecting an unconnected cable is not possible on regular PCs.